# primefaces scrollable tree element in a layoutUnit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a (simplified) layout:

```html
<p:layout fullpage='true'>
  <p:layoutUnit id='navUnit' position='west'>
    <h:form id='navForm'>
      <p:tree id='containment-navigator'>
        <p:treeNode/>
      </p:tree>
      <p:commandButton/>
    </h:form>
  </p:layoutUnit>
  <p:layoutUnit id='detail' position='center'/>
</p:layout>
```

I want the commandButton to always be visible.  I want the tree (containment-navigator) to fill the available space and to scroll if it doesn't fit.  I've tried a hundred things suggested here and there, but no matter what, the entire form (or perhaps the layoutUnit) ends up as the scrollable element and my button scrolls off the bottom of the unit along with the tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
#navForm {
    height: 100%;
}

#containment-navigator {
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

That minus 20 px leaves some space for the button.